# Binary search in rotated sorted array

Tags: java, binary-search

Looking for code review, optimizations, good practice recommendations etc.

```
/**
 * This is utility class for operations on rotated one-d array.
 * 
 * Note: a sorted array, reverse-sorted or a single element is array is not considered rotated sorted.
 * Eg:
 * [4, 5, 1, 2, 3] is condidered rotated.
 * While.
 * [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] is not considered rotated
 * 
 * 
 * Complexity: O (log n)
 */
public final class RotatedOneDSortedArray {

    private RotatedOneDSortedArray() { }

    /**
     * Searches for the value provided in the rotated sorted array.
     * If found, returns the index, of provided array, else returns -1.
     * If array is not rotated and sorted, then results are unpredictable
     * 
     * Throws an exception if array is null.
     * 
     * @param a the rotated sorted array
     * @param x the element to be searched
     * @returns the index at which the element is found, else returns -1
     */
    public static int binarySearchForRotatedArray(int[] a, int x) {
        int partitionIndex = findPartition(a, 0, a.length - 1);

        if (partitionIndex == -1) return -1;

        if (x >= a[0] && x <= a[partitionIndex]) {
            return binarySearch(a, 0, partitionIndex, x);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(a, partitionIndex + 1, a.length -1, x);
        }

    }

    private static int binarySearch (int[] a, int lb, int hb, int x) {
        assert a != null;

        if (lb > hb) return -1;

        int mid = (lb + hb)/2;

        if (a[mid] == x) return mid;

        if (a[mid] < x) {
            return binarySearch(a, mid + 1, hb, x);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(a, lb, mid - 1, x);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of greatest element of the rotated sorted array.
     * if array is not rotated sorted, results are unprodictable
     * 
     * @param a     the input array
     * @param lb    the lower bound
     * @param hb    the higher bound
     * @return      the index of the highest element in the array.
     */
    private static int findPartition(int[] a, int lb, int hb) {
        assert a!= null;

        if (lb == hb) return -1;

        int mid = (lb + hb)/2;

        if (a[mid] > a[mid + 1]) {
            return mid;
        }

        if (a[mid] > a[hb]) {
            // go right.
            return findPartition(a, mid + 1, hb);
        } else {
            // go left.
            return findPartition(a, lb, mid); // note i cannot do mid - 1
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // even length of the array.
        int[] a1 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected -1, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a1, -1));
        int[] a2 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected 1, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a2, 7));
        int[] a3 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected 5, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a3, 3));
        int[] a4 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected 2, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a4, 8));
        int[] a5 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected 3, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a5, 1));


        // odd length of the array. 
        int[] a6 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected -1, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a6, -1));
        int[] a7 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected 2, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a7, 7));
        int[] a8 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected 6, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a8, 3));
        int[] a9 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected 3, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a9, 8));
        int[] a10 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("Expected 4, Actual : " + binarySearchForRotatedArray(a10, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should put just a bit more effort an make it work for a "non-rotated" sorted buffer, since it's basically a special case of a rotated buffer (i.e. the case where the tail of the list is empty). If I got it right, that's the case where `(partitionIndex == -1)`, and it simply means you should do a binary search of the entire array. Also, the structure you are dealing with is more commonly called a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the structure you are dealing with is more commonly called a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). The Wikipedia link has several examples on how to efficiently provide thread safe read/write access (a producer/consumer queue), but what's more important is the idea that you can **abstract the access to your circular buffer to an interface**, so that callers deal with it like it's an ordinary list.

The interface might look something like this (sorry for my poor Java skills):

```
public interface IReadonlyList<T>
{
    // gets the item at the specified index
    T getItem(int index);

    // gets the length
    int length();
}
```

And the circular buffer implementation would simply offset the internal index before returning the requested value:

```
// note that _headOffset and _actualArray aren't
// assigned anywhere, it's just a concept

public class CircularBuffer<T> : IReadonlyList<T>
{
    private final int _headOffset;
    private final T[] _actualArray;

    public T getItem(int index)
    {
        var actualIndex = (index + _headOffset) % Length;
        return _actualArray[actualIndex];
    }

    public int length()
    {
        return _actualArray.Length;
    }
}
```

Wrapping the class in an interface like this allows you to use a general binary search algorithm you would use for a standard sorted list (and any other algorithm which would work on a non-circular buffer).

Comment: That is a nice and clean idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've done :

- enhanced the tests
- support sorted array (circular array with a shift of 0)
- remove recursion for optimisation and clearer signature

```
/**
 * This is utility class for operations on rotated one-d array.
 *
 * Complexity: O (log n)
 */
public final class RotatedOneDSortedArray {

    private RotatedOneDSortedArray() { }

    /**
     * Searches for the value provided in the rotated sorted array.
     * If found, returns the index, of provided array, else returns -1.
     * If array is not rotated and sorted, then results are unpredictable
     *
     * Throws an exception if array is null.
     *
     * @param a the rotated sorted array
     * @param x the element to be searched
     * @returns the index at which the element is found, else returns -1
     */
    public static int binarySearchForRotatedArray(int[] a, int x) {
        int partitionIndex = findPartition(a);

        if (partitionIndex == -1) return -1;

        if (x >= a[0] && x <= a[partitionIndex]) {
            return binarySearch(a, 0, partitionIndex, x);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(a, partitionIndex + 1, a.length -1, x);
        }

    }

    private static int binarySearch (int[] a, int lb, int hb, int x) {
        assert a != null;

        while (lb <= hb)
        {
            int mid = (lb + hb)/2;
            int midv = a[mid];
            if (midv < x) {
                lb = mid + 1;
            } else if (midv > x) {
                hb = mid -1;
            } else {
                return mid;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of greatest element of the rotated sorted array.
     * if array is not rotated sorted, results are unprodictable
     *
     * @param a     the input array
     * @return      the index of the highest element in the array.
     */
    private static int findPartition(int[] a) {
        assert a!= null;

        int lb = 0;
        int hb = a.length-1;

        // Check if rotation is 0
        if (a[lb] < a[hb])
            return hb;

        while (lb != hb)
        {
            int mid = (lb + hb)/2;

            if (a[mid] > a[mid + 1]) {
                return mid;
            } else if (a[mid] > a[hb]) {
                // go right.
                lb = mid + 1;
            } else {
                // go left.
                hb = mid; // note i cannot do mid - 1
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // even length of the array.
        int expected = 0; int actual = 0;
        int[] a1 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = -1; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a1, -1);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        int[] a2 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = 1; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a2, 7);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        int[] a3 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = 5; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a3, 3);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        int[] a4 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = 2; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a4, 8);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        int[] a5 = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = 3; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a5, 1);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);

        // odd length of the array.
        int[] a6 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = -1; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a6, -1);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        int[] a7 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = 2; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a7, 7);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        int[] a8 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = 6; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a8, 3);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        int[] a9 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = 3; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a9, 8);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        int[] a10 = {4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};
        expected = 4; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a10, 1);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);

        // properly sorted
        int[] a11 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        expected = -1; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a11, 0);
        expected = 0;  actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a11, 1);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        expected = 1;  actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a11, 2);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        expected = 2;  actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a11, 3);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        expected = 3;  actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a11, 4);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        expected = 4;  actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a11, 5);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        expected = 5;  actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a11, 6);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        expected = 6;  actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a11, 7);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);
        expected = -1; actual = binarySearchForRotatedArray(a11, 8);
        if (expected != actual) System.out.println("Expected " + expected + " , Actual : " + actual);

    }
}
```